# Rails jbuilder: how to build a JSON from an array with the key equals to the array values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, jbuilder

I'm a pretty new Rails developer, I'm using [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to build my view in the following way:

```
[:aaa, :bbb, :ccc].each do |value|
  json.value do |json| #<------ Here is my error!
    json.partial! foo.send(value)
  end
end
```

Everything works BUT the `json.value`, my response is the following (obviously):

```
[{
"value" => {...}
"value" => {...}
"value" => {...}
}]
```

I'd like to have this one instead:

```
[{
"aaa" => {...}
"bbb" => {...}
"ccc" => {...}
}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the guide:

> To define attribute and structure names dynamically, use the `set!`
>   method:
>
> ```
> json.set! :author do
>   json.set! :name, 'David'
> end
>
> # => "author": { "name": "David" }
> ```

The solution is so:

```
[:aaa, :bbb, :ccc].each do |value|
  json.set! value do |json|
    json.partial! foo.send(value)
  end
end
```